# Resolve ambiguous calls between a generic and a non-generic IList extension method in special circumstances

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have an extension function called `RemoveWhere`. It simply accepts a predicate and removes items from a list which satisfy the condition. I removed the implementation for clarity.

```
public static IList<object> RemoveWhere(this IList list, Func<object, bool> predicate, int offset = 0)
{
    ...
}

public static IList<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate, int offset = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

I needed this method for generic `IList<T>` and non-generic `IList` as well, because we have several scenarios where only a non-generic interface is available.

However, when I have a specific `List<T>` instance, I get an ambiguous call compile-time error because it implements both the generic and non-generic interface.

How could I resolve it without renaming one of the methods?

UPDATE

I'm looking for a general solution which would apply to all collections which possibly implement both interfaces. I currently use Visual Studio 2013 and targeting .NET 4.

UPDATE 2

It turns out that the ambiguous call issue only appears when I don't reference any member of `T` directly in the predicate. Example here.

```
class Person {}
class SpecialPerson : Person {}

var list = new List<Person>();
// this resolves to the generic version
list.RemoveWhere(e => e.Name.Contains("Peter");
// this gives ambiguous call compiler error
list.RemoveWhere(e => e is SpecialPerson);
```

Comment: Try to declare the first one like this: ... RemoveWhere(this System.Collections.IList list, ...

Comment: See if this declaration will resolve the issue: `    }
    public static T RemoveWhere(this T list, Func<object, bool> predicate, int offset = 0) where T : IList
    {
        
    }`

Comment: @jvanrhyn Yes, that resolves it, but now calling it on a `List<T>` will select this, less specific version without a strongly typed predicate, etc. I'll end up probably with putting these versions into separate namespaces.

Comment: No it isn't. And actually `IList<T>` does not implement `IList` interestingly enough. But that's not related to this.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I think I'm gonna put these into separate namespaces like `Utils.CollectionExtensions` and `Utils.CollectionExtensions.NonGeneric` or vice versa.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck If `IList<>` had inherited from `IList` (non-generic), the call would not have been ambiguous in the first place. In that case the overload with the more derived type would have been "better" and would have been preferred automatically by the overload resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this special case when I don't reference any member of `T` in the predicate I ended up adding the generic parameter to the call, helping out the compiler.

```
class Person {}
class SpecialPerson : Person {}

var list = new List<Person>();
// this resolves to the generic version
list.RemoveWhere(e => e.Name.Contains("Peter");
// this gives ambiguous call compiler error
list.RemoveWhere(e => e is SpecialPerson);
// if I help the compiler it resolves correctly
list.RemoveWhere<Person>(e => e is SpecialPerson);
```

Comment: Yes, you can also help the compiler with `list.RemoveWhere((Person e) => e is SpecialPerson);`. But it is a shame if most uses have a collection that is both `IList<>` and `IList`.

Comment: For me adding the type parameter looks a bit better, but you're right. There are several interesting parts in the .NET built-in collections world.

Answer (score 2):

If have tested this code and it calls the correct Extension for the different type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var genericList = new List<String>() {"a", "b"};
        var listImplementation = new MyList();

        var resultGeneric = genericList.RemoveWhere(x => x.Contains("s"));
        var resultImplemented = listImplementation.RemoveWhere(x => x.Equals(1));
    }
}

class MyList : IList
{
   ...
}

public static class JTest
{
    public static IList RemoveWhere(this IList list, Func<object, bool> predicate, int offset = 0)
    {
        return list;
    }

    public static IList<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate, int offset = 0)
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.. I don't know why it doesn't work at me. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and targeting .NEt 4. Which compiler version do you use?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási jvanrhyn is right. Your repro example from the question does not seem to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Wait! Replace with `var resultGeneric = genericList.RemoveWhere(x => true);` and the issue is reproduced! A little strange.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen gotcha, I tried using a member of `T` in the predicate and the compiler recognized that I want the generic version. In my code I don't directly use any member in the predicate either.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a third overload(!) which calls the right one, as in:

```
public static IList<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate, int offset = 0)
{
  return ((IList<T>)list).RemoveWhere(prdeicate, offset);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this is definitely an option, but I was looking for a generalized solution which would cover every scenario where a collection implements both interfaces. However I wasn't clear about this, so I will vote you up because this is a valid answer of course.